# Import Root Certificate of Google/iTunes into WebSphere Application Server - Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, worklight-security

I am trying to Configuring **WebSphere Application Server - Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1** to support applications in public app stores and   following this link : [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_applinks_google.html][1]

Its saying that I have to import Root Certificate of Google play into the WebSphere trust store. This is the part I got stuck since I don't know how to open liberty profile console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liberty profile does not have console yet. Whole configuration is held in server.xml file. 
In that file you will find reference to the keystore, like this:

```
<feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="password" />
```

If default settings are used you should have `key.jks` file in the `serverName\resources\security\key.jks`

Then you need to add cert there using some tool e.g. keytool, or ikeyman (if you have full WAS at hand). Example for keytool:

```
keytool -importcert -alias certAlias -file certificate.crt -keystore key.jks
```